# Can't find some Software (Like Adobe Reader) in the USC

Tags: 12.04, installation, apt

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I am not able to find Adobe reader or Gnu plot in the software centre. When I try to get all updates, the process goes through till about 95% and then doesn't proceed. Hence, I had to stop it there.

Can someone please help me to install these software's.

And also let me know why I am unable to view these on the software center screen.

Comment: sudo apt-get update

Comment: Can you run `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal, and tell us weather it has any errors?

Comment: 0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.200)] [Connecting to archive.canonical.com (91.189.92.150)]This is the message which I get and it does not proceed further

Answer (score 1):

For **Adobe Reader** you need to download it from the official adobe site.

Open the terminal **Ctrl-Alt-T** and type this

```
wget http://ardownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.1/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.1-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```

then

```
sudo dpkg -i AdbeRdr9
```

****Important****

If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu you will need to install this **first**

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```